# CDN SSL Authentication reliablity

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, phpmyadmin

I was having SSL on my main domain. which is let say , "example.com" & it only showed lock/HTTPS icon on "example.com" not any subdomain eg. abc.example.com , xyz.example.com also Lock /HTTPS was not showing on example.com/phpMyadmin , abc.example.com/phpMyadmin , xyz.example.com/phpMyadmin.

but after integrating CDN , I am getting SSL lock/ HTTPS on subdomains also e.g. abc.example.com , xyz.example.com & on abc.example.com/phpMyadmin , xyz.example.com/phpMyadmin also.

I am wondering is it a safe connection for using phpMyadmin under CDN's SSL ?

What other safer option are there instead of phpMyadmin?

Comment: If you trust your CDN, it's *reasonably* safe. phpMyAdmin is a regular source of compromises, though; you should consider using a desktop client for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz , u meanMySql Workbench ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I use Sequel Pro on my Mac.

Comment: That's great, well i couldn't download workbench. It kept me taking into loop to install pre requisites. then the same page would open.